# Centering Buttons in Material-UI and React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have successfully centered the `Hello There` button.
But my problem is, a little bit of lines are appearing on it.
I could put a `background-color: white` to solve it, but is there a better way to do this and a better coding? Like not using `position: absolute` etc....?

[CLICK HERE FOR CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wright-w4hs8u?file=/demo.js)

```
 <Stack
    alignItems={"center"}
    sx={{
      marginTop: 2,
      position: "absolute",
      display: "flex",
      left: 0,
      right: 0
    }}
  >
    <Button variant="outlined">Hello There</Button>
  </Stack>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Button` variant you are using is the `varian="outlined"` which  has a transparent background. So when is positioned above the dashed border they are shown behind it. In this case if you wan to keep this style of `Button` you have to add a `background-colour` of white to it.
Another option would be to use the `contained` variant like below but this would change the style of the button.

```
<Button variant="contained">
  Hello there
</Button>
```

**UPDATED**:

or (for any reason you don't want to add the background colour to the button) you can add using `:after` or `:before` at the button, an element that will be behind the button and hide the dashed border. As a solution is not optimal as this will not work for dynamic backgrounds, or if they have an image or even a gradient color.

```
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            position: "relative",
            zIndex: "1",
            "&:before": {
              content: `''`,
              background: "white",
              width: "100%",
              height: "10px",
              position: "absolute",
              zIndex: "-1"
            }
          }}
        >
          Hello There
        </Button>
```

Comment: I already stated in my question that I don't like to add background of white. If it is possible. But I would like it be outlined still

Comment: @Joseph in my answer I explained you the reason it is happening so you need somehow to hide this dashed border. The other way to to do it is to add an `:after` or `:before` element that will be behind the button and would hide the dashed border. if this is a solution that would work for you let me know and i can update my answer

Comment: Can you fork my codesandbox so it will be clearer?

Comment: Of course I can, but before I devote the time, please let me know if a solution like this is something that would work for you. What i explained in the previous comment is that another element with white background would be behind the button. It will not be visible directly and will act as something that would hide the dashed border. Of course it wouldn't be the ideal solution for dynamic page background colours, gradients or images.Please let me know if it makes sense to you

Comment: ok can you the :before and :after thing?

Comment: @Joseph i have updated the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-gianmarco-qhxxeq?file=/demo.js:2052-2452 and my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should be clearer but here is the answer of what I am thinking.

```
<Stack
sx={{
    marginTop: 2,
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%"
}}
>
<Button
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
    margin: "0px auto"
    }}
>
    Hello There
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer my question `But my problem is, a little bit of lines are appearing inside of the button. I could put a background-color: white to solve it, but is there a better way to do this?`

Comment: `<Stack spacing={1} sx={{ border: 'none' }}>
        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275, backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography
`
Could you kindly remove the border of parent <Stack> looks like border of parent stack is still there with grey color.

Comment: The dashed border needs to be there. Just not inside of the button